# Speed is getting lower using sockets

Tags: c#, sockets

Good day! I have a program that uses sockets to parse some info from urls. Program  Here some code from the thread:

```
var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);

using (s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    s.Connect(new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], 80));

    if (!s.Connected)
        continue;

    var requestS = "GET http://" + host + " HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n" +
                   "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                   "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    var bytesSent1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(requestS); 
    var bytesReceived1 = new Byte[1000];

    s.Send(bytesSent1, bytesSent1.Length, 0);

    var bytes = 0;

    do
    {
        bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived1, bytesReceived1.Length, 0);
        content = content + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytesReceived1, 0, bytes);
    }
    while (bytes > 0);

    s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, new LingerOption(false, 0));
    s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, false);
    s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    s.Disconnect(true);
    s.Close();
    s.Dispose();
}
```

At first time speed is about 50mbit/s but after some time it is decreasing and become 10-15mbit/s. Help me to find out why? There are some connection that didn't shut down?

The thing is that there are list of different urls which i rotate in thread and make Get responses. Here my thread code. Places where i wrote // request using sockets  contains request code that i described at the top of the topic.

```
public void MainThread()
{
List<string> links = new List<string>();
// input links code
foreach (var link1 in links)
{
try
{
var host = new Regex(@"^[^\/]+").Match(link1.Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "").Replace("www.", "").TrimEnd('/')).Groups[0].Value;
string content = "";
Socket s = null;
IPHostEntry hostEntry;
hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host);         

// request using sockets

// here some code to work with answer text

// another request using sockets

}
catch{}
lock (lockOperations)
operations++;
}
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but a tip: you don't need to call `Close`/`Dispose` as `s` is used in the using statement which will close and dispose of the object.

Comment: Any reason you did not use [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)? Ever heard of HTTP socket reuse?

Comment: what makes you think that the returned content is using your default local encoding??

Comment: How are you measuring the transfer rate?  Can you download content from the same source using another application (e.g. Chrome, Internet Explorer) to see if you see the same drop in transfer speed?  Depending on what your source is, perhaps your ISP is throttling the bandwidth.  Do you see the same results if you run the application on a totally different network against a different source? Is there more to this story (e.g. are you spinning up several threads that are executing this task?)?

Comment: Could you please tell me more details about which encoding should i use and some more info about HTTP socket reuse? I am not a professional programmer so this is important for me.

Comment: Yes, the number of thread are more then 100.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of IO asynchronously, you may wish to consider looking at: *IO completion port*.  ASIDE: on a previous project I came across a limitation in Windows Server 2003, whereby, there was a maximum number of concurrent connections that an application could make.  If I recall the number was ~128.  As we approached ~100, our performance started to drop. A developer who built a socket server later told me that he too had seen this and that he found out that this limitation did not exist in the more  expensive flavors of Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Instead of explicitly creating 100 threads, consider: (1) using a queue with worker threads [2 x NumberOfCpu], or (2) use a thread pool.

Comment: Keep it simple - build a small prototype application: [1] forget threads for now, [2] use `WebRequest` to retrieve the data from the source (Abbas), [3] use `StringBuilder` and `Append` (Thorsten Dittmar), [4] make sure you care calculating your transfer rate properly.  Then start keeping track of your transfer rate from different sources.

Comment: The HTTP *headers* are encoded in ASCII with some restricted characters ([RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)). The *content* is encoding in accordance with the charset in the [`Content-Type`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) header in the response. Simply use `WebRequest` and you won't have to deal with this problem.

Comment: HTTP socket reuse allows a client (your app) to fetch *multiple* responses on the same socket, eliminating the need for negotiating a new socket for each request. Again, simply use `WebRequest` to avoid handling this manually.

Comment: I recommend reading [Understanding System.Net Connection Management and ServicepointManager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2005/01/02/345411.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `StringBuilder` and `Append` to it instead of using `content = content + ...`. This copies the string every time.

Also, did you consider it could be that your code doesn't have a problem, but the server? Maybe the server slows down?

And: Where's the code where you measure the rate? I can't see it in your sample?